# Replacing ChildNode values with html content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Iam trying to replace a node value with an html content. but when i try this the html tags are shown in html page instead of the applied style.

```
<style>
    .YellowSelection {
        background: yellow;
    }
</style>

var capturedText = 'test';
var changedText = '<span class="YellowSelection">test</span> Day';
htmlreplace(capturedText, changedText);

function htmlreplace(capturedText, changedText, element) {  

var nodes = element.childNodes;
for (var n=0; n<nodes.length; n++) {
    if (nodes[n].nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        var r = new RegExp(capturedText, 'gi');
        console.log(nodes[n]);
        nodes[n].textContent  = nodes[n].textContent.replace(r, changedText);
    } else {
        htmlreplace(capturedText, changedText, nodes[n]);
    }
}
}
```

[image]

Updated (Complete Code).

```
<style>
    .YellowSelection {
       color: yellow;
    }
</style>

function returnSelection() {

    var capturedText;
    var changedText;

    capturedText = window.getSelection().toString().replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
    changedText = '<span class="YellowSelection">' + capturedText + '</span>';


        htmlreplace(capturedText, changedText);

    }
}

function htmlreplace(capturedText, changedText, element) {    
    if (!element) element = document.body;    
    var nodes = element.childNodes;
    for (var n=0; n<nodes.length; n++) {
        if (nodes[n].nodeType === 3) {
            var r = new RegExp(capturedText, 'gi');
            nodes[n].innerHTML = nodes[n].textContent.replace(r, changedText);
        } else {
            htmlreplace(capturedText, changedText, nodes[n]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where `htmlreplace()` is defined ?

Comment: i have corrected the code now. Iam more concerned about this line - nodes[n].textContent  = nodes[n].textContent.replace(r, changedText);

Comment: you are setting the text content which  sets or returns the textual content of the specified node, and all its descendants. , i think you should for for innerHTML if you want to inject the html element

Comment: could you please provide a sample?

Comment: Won't https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild be very usefull here?

Comment: @Shilly he want to replace text not node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `textContent` that will change the text and not HTML content, try to use `innerHTML` instead of `textContent` :

```
nodes[n].innerHTML = nodes[n].textContent.replace(r, changedText);
```

Hope this will helps.

```js
var capturedText = 'test';
var changedText = '<span class="YellowSelection">test</span> Day';

var node_1 = document.getElementById('div1');
node_1.innerHTML = node_1.textContent.replace(capturedText, changedText);

/*********/

var node_2 = document.getElementById('div2');
node_2.textContent = node_2.textContent.replace(capturedText, changedText);
```

```css
.YellowSelection{
  color: green;  
}
```

```html
<div id='div1'>Div 1 test</div>
<div id='div2'>Div 2 test</div>
```

Comment: Tried this already. but dont work!! I will provide a complete code sample.

Comment: Let me check this out. Actually iam trying to write a 'chrome extension' plugin and when i try to execute this, it is not working but it is not showing any error though.